# Appcelerator Titanium (Alloy) | How to find a error? or exception?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am working on a project, and everything was working fine. However, suddenly I am getting below error

> [ERROR] :
>   [ERROR] :  (C:\Users\user.name.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\alloy\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:189:18)
>
> [ERROR] :  (C:\Users\abdul.aleem.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\alloy\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:197:11)
>
> [ERROR] :  (C:\Users\abdul.aleem.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\alloy\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:664:9)
>
> [ERROR] :  Alloy compiler failed
>   TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
>
> [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

I know I had mistakenly written something on JS file or XML file, and now I am unable to find the exact cause of the error. The studio is throwing to a general exception. 
How to find the exact location or cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this with the same 5.0.2 version:

```
[ERROR] :  Error generating AST for "/Users/fokkezb/dev/studio/TestAlloy/app/controllers/index.js"
[ERROR] :  Unexpected token punc «{», expected punc «(»
[ERROR] :  line 1, column 17, position 17
[ERROR] :  Alloy compiler failed
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
```

If you figure out the cause, could you create a [JIRA](http://jira.appcelerator.org) ticket with a reproducible test case and steps so we ca fix this?

Comment: No, you are not getting my point. For example i have written 10 XML files and everything is working fine. somehow in one of my XML i have mistakenly written a view tag like: <View id="dummy/> something </View> and it throws a general exception like XML parsing error. so what i have supposed to do? check all XML files? wont it will slow my development?

Comment: I've tried the same with an XML typo and it also gives me the exact error and location. So what you see is a bug and not how it is supposed to work. So please create a JIRA ticket with reproducible steps and environment info so we can fix it.